# The proper way to get a value from a sensor

Tags: multithreading, raspberry-pi, freeze, sensors, adc

I'm coding a device that works with a pressure sensor (with a RPi and via a MCP3008 ADC).
When looking for its value `MCP3008(0).value` the program may freeze.
I'm looking for a way to overcome that.
I thought a good option was to call it in a thread but I struggle to code it right and I'm not sure it is the best approach.

So far I tested many ways but none of them gave good results everytime.
Please let me know how you would manage this.

Here is below my current code:

```
class PressureMeasurementThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.stop_event = threading.Event()
        self.pressure = None

    def run(self):
        try:
            x = 0
            p_list = []
            while x < 5:
                p = 0
                error = 0
                while not 0.05 <= p <= 0.99:
                    if error != 0:
                        time.sleep(0.02)
                    p = MCP3008(0).value
                    error += 1
                x += 1
                p_list.append(p)
                time.sleep(0.01)
            self.pressure = p_list
        except Exception as e1:
            print(f"Error while measuring pressure: {e1}")

    def stop(self):
        self.stop_event.set()

    def reset(self):
        self.pressure = None
        self.stop_event.clear()


measurement_thread = PressureMeasurementThread()


def pressure_measure():
    if measurement_thread.is_alive():
        measurement_thread.stop()
    measurement_thread.reset()
    measurement_thread.start()
    return measurement_thread.pressure
```

Then I call pressure_measure() and delete the abnormal values.
With that code I get errors stating thread can only be started once.

Comment: Re, "I tested many ways but none of them gave good results everytime." You will be more likely to get useful answers if you can describe what kind of "results" you are looking for, and how the results that you actually got failed to meet your expectation.

Comment: FYI: The `measurement_thread.start()` call will fail on the second call and, on every call thereafter. The [documentation for `Thread.start()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start) says, "... must be called _at most once per thread object..._"

Comment: The "result" I'm looking for is only to get the pressure everytime, with no errors such as thread trying to start multiple times, pressure = None, freeze, etc.
At first I'm wondering if threading is the way to go for this purpose actually.